# Making madeleines without the special pan?

Tags: baking

I don't have the special pan or any cupcake or muffin tins.

Can I just plop spoonfuls on a cookie sheet? Does anyone know whether I have to alter the recipe? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never made madeleines myself, but looking at the recipe and reading Elendil's concerns about the batter running, I would think you could fashion an impromptu "madeleine pan" out of aluminum foil.  It won't be the easiest thing in the world, and you're not going to get the perfect shell look, but I think you'll be able to get the right general shape and depth with a little craftwork.

These look like something I would love to make, so I did a little research and a few people said they poured the batter into a sheet pan (in a very thin layer) and then cut them into squares after.  Not exactly the same final product, but if you're dying to use the batter I think it would still taste great.  As Elendil suggested, the people who said they were able to make them on a cookie sheet found that they were very flat and crispy (though still tasty).

Comment: Most complete answer given the other ones I've read. Thanks for the aluminum foil idea!!

Answer (score 1):

You really need something that will contain the batter, as in the initial stages of baking the fat will melt and the whole lot will run into one big cake. Muffin/cake tins are relatively cheap and easy to come by.

Answer (score 1):

i am in the same situation as you, and i've read that while you can use muffin tins (or mini ones?) for madeleines, using actual madeleine molds are really the best because their shape ensures that the finished product will have the right "crispness" to the edges that everyone adores. but i'm sure that they would taste the same however you make them -- it's just the texture will be a bit different.

Answer (score -1):

We're making them tonight using "whoopie" sheet mold - 12/- almost the same depth

They turned out great.  - The 15 minutes cooks.com recipe requires is a bit much for my "hot" oven.

Have to make 48 - we'll see what happens with the next batch. to be continued

Comment: What is "whoopie" sheet mold?

Comment: @rumtscho I would assume a mold for whoopie pies, ala http://www.crateandbarrel.com/jump.aspx?bid=1015450&t=6&a=1552&s=408983&ef_id=81hOwV1hGm8AAA17:20120410161011:s